# Why do String.format methods have data types?

Tags: java, string, format

I'm referring to `%s` and `%d`, for example. Why is it required that the data type is should be defined in the format? For example, why not have a `%@` for any type? Note that this is a general question for any programming language with a formatter function, like Java.

Comment: You mean `%s` that prints the string version for any object type?

Comment: In C the function doesn't know the data types it was passed, so it relies on these format strings to figure them out. In java the data type is passed, here it acts just as a kind of failsafe in case you messed something up. Also since some formatting-options are dependent on the datatype these could all not be used with your `%@`, so `%@` would be a very limited specifier requiring a lot of effort (figuring out the type) to work.

Comment: `%04x` or `%6.2f` are useful and in those cases a redundancy seems appropriate. And then there is the alternative `MessageFormat` with `{}` parameters - and internationalisation (numbers with thousand separators and such).